# Codeigniter 3 with angularjs [SPA] file organization

Tags: jquery, angularjs, codeigniter

I have an up and running CI application. It isn't a SPA, so, for every request CI rebuild the page from scratch. The entire UI lives inside the /view folder.

I have organized my view files in order to easily include common parts of the page, for example I have a layout.php view and two type of sidebar.php view, one sidebar for logged user, one sidebar for admins user.

I use a lot of jQuery and ajax calls. 
I also kept apart all the Controllers that handle only ajax requests.

I'd like to switch this app in a SPA using AngularJS. 
I'm not familiar with AngularJS, and I won't write the code, a skilled front-end developer will do, but I want to know how things must be organized, in the good way.

I'm in design phase, pen and paper, and my paper is blank!

For example, does CI will handle only ajax calls? 
I don't need a single view file anymore?!

All the UI will be in .html file and handle by Angular with routes ... so I have to write both sidebar (for users and for admins) and Angular will show the links based on the user role? If you browse the app or look at the source code you can see all the links, even those for admins, isn't it?

Can I still check my users requests using the CI session?

I know this sounds pretty confused. Maybe, if someone could share a case study or a project or code sample that use CI and angular JS where I can learn from.

I googled this, and I found only the to-do app, or similar. 
It's too simple. 
I'd like to know the best practices (or at least a good example of code organization) when you have a dashboard, users roles for what you can see and what you can do, and stuff like that.

Thank you for help.

Comment: buy a book, watch some tutorials and after that come back here if you need any more help